# Disable add option admin page Django Taggit

Tags: django, django-admin, django-taggit

I am using django-taggit to attach some tags to models in django admin page. But I want to limit the creation of these tags to just one place but not the attaching process of tags to models. Is there a way to disable the add option on the taggit autocomplete widget?

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a wagtail specific feature, it looks like free_tagging = False is what you need?

See https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#disabling-free-tagging